# Laravel retrieve only specific fields from each item of collection

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I may be missing something extremely trivial, but is it possible to retrieve specific columns/fields from models when grabbing a collection rather then returning the entire item's fields?

Here is my query:

```
$items = Items::where('visible', true)->take(10)->get();
```

This obviously returns each item in there entirety, including unique id's, and other fields i dont want to be fetched... how can i refine this query to just select specific fields from the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel Query Builder `get()` function receives array of columns which you need to fetch.

`$items = Items::where('visible', true)->take(10)->get(['column_1', 'column_2']);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `select()` method to do this:

```
$items = Items::select(['column_1', 'column_2']'])->where('visible', true)->take(10)->get();
```

Source: [Latavel Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Query Builder gives a huge flexibility to write this types of query. 
You can use select(), get(), all() methods.

```
Items::where('visible', true)->take(10)->get('col_1', 'col_2');
```

**OR**

```
Items::select('col_1', 'col_2')->where('visible', true)->take(10)->get();
Items::select(['col_1', 'col_2'])->where('visible', true)->take(10)->get();
```